# How to add "id" to li using mootools

Tags: mootools

in my code(mootools) im trying to add a new li to the ul and the li contains a hyper link. I tried the below code:

```
var newLi = new Element('li#internet_sub', { html: '<a style="BACKGROUND-POSITION: 13px -34px" class="sec_net_1" href="javascript:void(0);" id="sec_net_hsi" >Internet</a>' });
```

and this also:

```
 var newLi = new Element('li id="internet_sub"', { html: '<a style="BACKGROUND-POSITION: 13px -34px" class="sec_net_1" href="javascript:void(0);" id="sec_net_hsi" >Internet</a>' });
```

Both of them worked in IE but not in Fire fox.. When i removed adding id to li like below, it worked in Firefox also.

```
 var newLi = new Element('li', { html: '<a style="BACKGROUND-POSITION: 13px -34px" class="sec_net_1" href="javascript:void(0);" id="sec_net_hsi" >Internet</a>' });
```

Please tell me how to add id to the new li and it should work inboth the browsers..

Answer (score 0):

I added id at the end like how i added html.. and it worked. The solution is this:

```
var newLi = new Element('li', { html: '<a cat="tech" style="BACKGROUND-POSITION: 13px -34px" class="sec_net_1" href="javascript:void(0);" id="sec_net_hsi">Internet</a>', id: 'internet_sub' });
```